# how to prevent data tables excel export functionaity from copying page title in the first row

Tags: datatables

When trying to export or copy a data table to excel, the downloaded file has the title of the web page in the header row. This happens on their example page. How to prevent this from happening? This doesn't happen for CSV format.

[data tables basic export example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()). You can specify null in the function to avoid a title.